# Pip installed package shows error on import

Tags: python, pip

I have installed textract, python-docx, docx using pip.

> pip install textract

The packages were successfully installed. I was able to see them when I execute *pip list*

But when I try to import these packages it shows an import error suggesting that the module does not exist.

> import textract
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> ImportError: No module named textract

I am using a Linux system. What exactly is the issue and how can I start solving it?

Comment: are you using default python 2.7 or python 3.x in linux???

Comment: Probably you have installed the package on a different version of python from the one you are calling

Comment: You might be using `python3` try `pip3 install textract`

Comment: Run `pip -V` and `python -V` and check whether the Python version matches.

Comment: I gave the commands. It says,

pip 18.0 from <location> (python 3.5) and Python 2.7.12

Comment: So you installed `textract` for Python 3.5; `python3 -c "import textract" ` will work fine. If you need `textract` for Python 2.7, use `pip2`: `pip2 install textract`. You may need to install `pip2` first, e.g. `apt install python-pip`, depending on linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
python -m pip install packagename
```

You will use python2's pip and the package will install for that version.